# Problema al usar createsuperuser Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

tengo un problema. Sucede que al utilizar "python manage.py createsuperuser
" me permite sólo configurar el usuario pero no me aparece ni el password ni el correo, al contrario, sólo me aparecen errores.

Soy nueva en esto, no sé si me salté algo. Agrego el código:

> admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User, Post, Comment, PostView, Like

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(PostView)
admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(Like)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser



class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

> settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'carros',
    'bootstrap4',
    'posts',
]


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

]

SITE_ID = 1
AUTH_USER_MODEL='posts.User'

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Los errores que me aparecen son los siguientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Agrego los modelos

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser



class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username



class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField()
    thumbnail=models.ImageField()
    publish_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_update=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug=models.SlugField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class PostView(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Like(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento, el error que tienes hasta el ultimo:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no existe la relación <<post_user>>
LINE 1: ..set"."is_active", "post_user"."date_joined" FROM "posts_use...
```

Te esta indicando que en tu modelo Post debes tener un ForeignKey a un usuario, comparte este modelo para poder ver como esta.

Analizando un poco entonces te pregunto, ¿ya generaste todas tus migraciones y las aplicaste con makemigrations y migrate antes? Ya que esta es una opción, que no hayas generado las migraciones o no las hayas aplicados y por lo mismo no existe esa relación. Tus migraciones deben de estar en nombre_app/migrations/0001_initial.py, etc. Puedes verificarlo de esta manera:

```
python manage.py makemigrations nombre_app
```

Y ver si te genera alguna migración, si es así entonces aplícala con migrate.

También, ¿ya verificaste que tu aplicación donde tienes el modelo Post este en el INSTALLED_APPS de tu settings.py?

Actualizado
Puedes probar haciendo esto, comentas django.contrib.admin:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
# 'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',

```
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'carros',
'bootstrap4',
'posts',
```

]

Y comentas la url:

```
# path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

Ejecutas

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Si se aplican correctamente las migraciones entonces descomentas 'django.contrib.admin' de tus installed_apps y la url.

Comment: De hecho al aplicar **migrate** me aparece el siguiente error: `django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency posts.0001_initial on database 'default'.
` @Kevin

Comment: Ya actualice la respuesta.

Comment: ohhh voy a intentarlo, muchas gracias @kevin